# Regex match whole expression instead of 2 matches

Tags: javascript, regex

```
respuesta_email.innerHTML="We\'re sorry, the e-mail could not be sent";}else{if(response=~'1'){var respuesta_email=document.getElementById("respuesta_email"); respuesta_email.innerHTML="E-mail sent successfully";
```

I wand to match the strings for **respuesta_email_innerHTML**

Matcher: `respuesta_email.innerHTML.*;/g`

Expected results (2 matches):

```
"We\'re sorry, the e-mail could not be sent";
"E-mail sent successfully";
```

Real result = whole input text.

Why is that happening and how I can solve this?

Comment: Use `respuesta_email.innerHTML="([^"]*)";/g`

Comment: working perfect, thank you.

Comment: @cityboycity1, Why do you need to do such a horrible parsing?